# Getting all related fields to related field in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this DB structure:

[image: DB stucture]

`classroom_user` is Elqouent many-to-many pivot.

**User.php**:

```
public function classrooms() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(ClassRoom::class, 'classroom_user', 'classroom_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

**ClassRoom.php**:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'classroom_user', 'user_id', 'classroom_id');
}
```

I have a `$user` and want to write Eloquent method which gets all users who are in at least one of classrooms the `$user`also is in. Something like `$user->classrooms->users`. But this falls with error `Property [users] does not exist on this collection instance.`. How can I do this?

Comment: What code are you using to build the eloquent query?

Comment: @HalfCrazed the problem is I haven't got any idea what code can be used in this case

Comment: What's the query you execute to get the `$user`?

Comment: @Hamoud  `Auth::user()`

Comment: I think you don't need to go through the user, you can start your query something like this Classroom::whereHas()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like this:

```
$users = User::whereHas('classrooms', function($query) {
    $query->whereHas('users', function($query) {
        $query->where('id',  auth()->user()->id);
    });
})->get();
```

You could store this as a scope in your `User` model:

```
public function scopeClassmatesOf($query, $user)
{
    $query->whereHas('classrooms', function($query) use($user) {
        $query->whereHas('users', function($query) use($user) {
            $query->where('id',  $user->id);
        });
    })
}
```

And then call it from a controller like:

```
$user = auth()->user();

$users = User::classmatesOf($user)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your asking for `users` of a collection. `$user->classrooms` is a collection of classrooms.

If you do `$user->classrooms->first()->users` you will get all the users from the first classroom.

To get all users from all classrooms, you can do something like;

```
$users = $user->classrooms->map(function ($classroom) {
    return $classroom->users;
});
```

Note that will return duplicate users and authenticated user him self witin the collection. So, you might need to do some filtering to the result.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
public function classmates() {
        $self = $this;
        $a = User::with('classrooms')->whereHas('classrooms', function ($query) use ($self) {
            $query->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($self) {
                $query->where('users.id', $self->id);
            });
        });
        return $a;
    }
```